# Работа с Gif-файлами в проекте Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, изображения, gif

С бэка получаем зашированную строку Base64 (до кодирования это gif картинка), которую нужно декодировать и сохранить в кэш приложения (кэшируется с помощью Glide). Позже требуется взять этот файл из кэша (файл хранится в кэше без расширения) в Gif-расширении и показать пользователю.

Проблема в том, что взятый с кэша представляется пользователю в виде обычной картинки(только первый фрейм), а не в Gif.

Как отображать пользователю именно Gif-картинку в описанных условиях?

Comment: Как я понимаю по причине экономии ресурсов Андроид до API 28 не поддерживал GIF-анимацию из коробки. Либо сторонние библиотеки, либо API28+ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedImageDrawable

Comment: а как вы вызываете Glide ? попробуйте указать формат по типу Glide.with(app).asGif().load(a.myUrl)).into(myView)

Comment: А если вопрос в том как взять первый фрейм из GIF, то лучше это делать на беке, а не тянуть целый GIF, чтобы взять только первый фрейм. Пожалейте пользователя.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja нет, нужно анимировать целый гиф.

Comment: @Wlad пробовали, не вышло.

Comment: может глупый вопрос, но все же... а вы уверены, что перекодировали в Base64 всю gif, а не только первый фрейм?

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека Glide [поддерживает](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/gif/GifDrawable.html) формат GIF.

Допустим, у нас есть ImageView:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Загружаем GIF из ресурсов в эту ImageView и все начинает анимироваться:

```kotlin
Glide.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.my_gif_image)
    .into(myImageView)
```

Если вам нужно управлять количеством циклов GIF-анимации, то можно создать такой класс:

```kotlin
class GifViewTarget(
    private val imageView: ImageView,
    private val loopCount: Int
) : ImageViewTarget<Drawable>(imageView) {
    override fun setResource(resource: Drawable?) {
        if (resource is GifDrawable) {
            resource.setLoopCount(loopCount)
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(resource)
    }
}
```

Тогда GIF можно загрузить так:

```kotlin
Glide.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.my_gif_image)
    .into(GifViewTarget(myImageView, loopCount = 3))
```